Cannot run npm install package
I encounter problem when doing my NPM install any package which I think it is because I have once delete my package-lock.json file. Below is the screenshot of the error. Do you has any suggestion to solve it?


npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: @hookform/devtools@4.3.1
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.13.5
npm error   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm error     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.13.5
npm error     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm error       @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @hookform/devtools@4.3.1
npm error       node_modules/@hookform/devtools
npm error         dev @hookform/devtools@"^4.3.1" from the root project
npm error       6 more (@mui/lab, @mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, ...)
npm error     @emotion/react@"^11.1.5" from @hookform/devtools@4.3.1
npm error     node_modules/@hookform/devtools
npm error       dev @hookform/devtools@"^4.3.1" from the root project
npm error     6 more (@mui/lab, @mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, ...)
npm error   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.13.5
npm error   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm error     @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @hookform/devtools@4.3.1
npm error     node_modules/@hookform/devtools
npm error       dev @hookform/devtools@"^4.3.1" from the root project
npm error     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/lab@6.0.0-beta.18
npm error     node_modules/@mui/lab
npm error       @mui/lab@"^6.0.0-beta.18" from the root project
npm error     5 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, ...)
npm error   104 more (@emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks, ...)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17 || ^18" from @hookform/devtools@4.3.1
npm error node_modules/@hookform/devtools
npm error   dev @hookform/devtools@"^4.3.1" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.3.1
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17 || ^18" from @hookform/devtools@4.3.1
npm error   node_modules/@hookform/devtools
npm error     dev @hookform/devtools@"^4.3.1" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\HP ProBook 430 G7\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-12T02_47_53_750Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HP ProBook 430 G7\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-12T02_47_53_750Z-debug-0.log 



I want to install this package. Hope anyone can help

(1) don't show pictures of text, show text. (2) the error is pretty much telling you what's wrong: there's a versions incompatibility with the version of React that's being used (v19) and the version that a dependency works with (v16-v18).


Do not post text in images, edit the question to remove the image and post the text itself. 2. Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore the error like you are now. The error tells you what the issue is. 3. react-hot-toast is a dead library that requires react 16, like the message shows. https://github.com/timolins/react-hot-toast/issues/380


your react version is not competible with that hookform/devtools insted its because that toast plugin is using older version of react. so if possible you can downgrade your react version to version 18, but not recomended. so you better use alternative dependancy like this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify
npm i react-toastify

